# How to send invoices through Amazon MWS API?

Tags: api, email, amazon-mws, invoice

I'm trying to send invoices to my customers through the Amazon MWS API. I know how to get the buyer's information for creating the invoice (PDF), but how can I send it to my customers through Amazon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [GetOrder](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_GetOrder.html) operation on the [Order API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_Overview.html).

With this operation, you can obtain the buyer contact information (BuyerEmail, BuyerName, ShippingAddress).

For a standard order, this information is available only if the order status is Unshipped, PartiallyShipped or Shipped. You won't get the buyer email if it's an Amazon gift.

Comment: This might sound a bit stupid, but how would I sent the invoice to the buyer then?

Comment: I should get some sleep. If I have the mail, then I can obviously send the email.